# SQL replace ampersands in XML with 'and'

Tags: xml, replace, xquery

I want to replace ampersands, showing as `&amp;` in XML stored in a SQL database.

The structure of the XML is...

```
<xs:simpleType name="ImportedData_Space_TypeType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:enumeration value="SupportSpace" />
  <xs:enumeration value="Teach&amp;ResSpace" />
  <xs:enumeration value="Teach&amp;ResSpecialistSpace" />
 </xs:restriction>
```

I'm trying to return a view and need to return the `&amp;` as `and`

I had a look at xquery but not sure if this is the best way?

Comment: This is much easier to do with XSLT -- the identity template, overridden by a template matching `ImportedData_Space_TypeType/text()` and in the overriding template simply: `<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&amp;', 'and')"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the replace-function, e.g.

```
declare variable $test := <ImportedData_Space_TypeType>Teach&amp;ResSpace</ImportedData_Space_TypeType>;
<ImportedData_Space_TypeType>{replace($test, "&amp;", "and")}</ImportedData_Space_TypeType>
```

Using XQuery Update you can also transform this, e.g.:

```
copy $c := $test
modify replace value of node $c with replace($c, "&amp;", "and")
return $c
```